# Twitter SDK requestCode

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm implementing log in with Twitter:
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login

Which utilizes `onActivityResult` for its callback. This is fine but `onActivityResult` is multi purpose and one normally differentiates using `requestCode`.

However I can't find anywhere in the SDK how to differentiate this Twitter `requestCode`. Most Libraries provide an enum or a final static number or something!

Does anyone know where in the Twitter SDK I can find a reference to this `requestCode`? I'd really appreciate any help at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I asked this question of Twitter themselves, for all looking:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/android-twitter-requestcode-in-onactivityresult/38592/2?u=solo4solo

This works:

```
if(requestCode == TwitterAuthConfig.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE){
```